# Failed: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined - karma jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I tried to test my angular component by using karma and jasmine, here i am getting error "Failed: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined".

This is my test case:Here my intention is to validate a button if two particular fields having input.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchPanelComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Well, `overlayContainerElement` is undefined. Without knowing what it is, we cannot help you.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Updated, if you find the solution please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: You never give value to `overlayContainerElement`. Of course it's undefined. This has nothing to do with Angular or testing, just follow the variables.